# DbSet doesn't have a Find method in EF7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create a generic repository to access my database. In EF6 I was able to do that in order to get a specific entity:

```
protected IDbSet<T> dbset;

public T Get(object id)
{
    return this.dbset.Find(id);
}
```

DbSet in EF7 is missing a Find method. Is there a way to implement the above piece of code?

Comment: This is tracked here: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/797

Comment: NEWS: `Find` method shipped today with EF Core 1.1.0.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a very crude, incomplete, and untested implementation of `.Find()` as an extension method. If nothing else, it should get you pointed in the right direction.

The real implementation is tracked by [#797](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/797).

```cs
static TEntity Find<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set, params object[] keyValues)
    where TEntity : class
{
    var context = ((IAccessor<IServiceProvider>)set).Service.GetService<DbContext>();

    var entityType = context.Model.GetEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
    var key = entityType.GetPrimaryKey();

    var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>();

    var i = 0;
    foreach (var property in key.Properties)
    {
        var keyValue = keyValues[i];
        entries = entries.Where(e => e.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue == keyValue);
        i++;
    }

    var entry = entries.FirstOrDefault();
    if (entry != null)
    {
        // Return the local object if it exists.
        return entry.Entity;
    }

    // TODO: Build the real LINQ Expression
    // set.Where(x => x.Id == keyValues[0]);
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
    var query = set.Where((Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)
        Expression.Lambda(
            Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(parameter, "Id"),
                Expression.Constant(keyValues[0])),
            parameter));

    // Look in the database
    return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Hi Brice, just curious if you have an updated version of this. I'm stuck with the line `var entityType = context.Model.GetEntityType(typeof(TEntity));`; since context has no Model property. I've changed `var context = ((IAccessor<IServiceProvider>)set).Service.GetService<DbContext>();` to `var context = ((IAccessor<IServiceProvider>)set).Service.GetService(typeof(DbContext));`

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I don't think `Model` has moved since we put it there; it's still in the nightly builds. To get the generic version of `GetService`, add `using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;`

Comment: Many thanks! I found the generic `IAccessor` in `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure`, but that makes a whole lot more sense that I'd need to use a `GetService()` that returns more than just an object. Cheers!

Comment: If your id field is not named `Id`, change `Expression.Property(parameter, "Id"),` to `Expression.Property(parameter, key.Properties[0].Name),`

Comment: I added Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure and I changed line into var context = ((IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>)set).Service.GetService<DbContext>();. Still I have errors: 'DbSet<TEntity>' does not contain a definition for 'Service' and no extension method 'Service' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet<TEntity>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) and 'IModel' does not contain a definition for 'GetEntityType' and no extension method 'GetEntityType' accepting a first argument of type 'IModel' could be found (are you missing...

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I couldn't find the `IAccessor` generic in `Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure`, or anywhere else, for that matter.  Am I missing some reference?

Answer (score 19):

In case you are using **EF 7.0.0-rc1-final**, below you find a small update for the code presented by @bricelam in the previous answer. By the way, thank you very much @bricelam - your code was extremely useful for me.

Here are my *dependencies* under "project.config":

```cs
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta8"
}
```

And below is the extension method for **DbSet.Find(TEntity)**:

```cs
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Microsoft.Data.Entity.Extensions
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static TEntity Find<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set, params object[] keyValues) where TEntity : class
        {
            var context = ((IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>)set).GetService<DbContext>();

            var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
            var key = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();

            var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>();

            var i = 0;
            foreach (var property in key.Properties)
            {
                entries = entries.Where(e => e.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue == keyValues[i]);
                i++;
            }

            var entry = entries.FirstOrDefault();
            if (entry != null)
            {
                // Return the local object if it exists.
                return entry.Entity;
            }

            // TODO: Build the real LINQ Expression
            // set.Where(x => x.Id == keyValues[0]);
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
            var query = set.Where((Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)
                Expression.Lambda(
                    Expression.Equal(
                        Expression.Property(parameter, "Id"),
                        Expression.Constant(keyValues[0])),
                    parameter));

            // Look in the database
            return query.FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed :)

Comment: Suggestion: you have a capture to a modified closure, which makes this break.  You should change the `foreach` loop to: `var i1 = i;
                entries = entries.Where(e => e.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue == keyValues[i1]);i++`

Answer (score 9):

Can't comment because of reputation, but if you use RC2 (or later?) you should use

```
var context = set.GetService<ICurrentDbContext>().Context;
```

instead of

```
var context = set.GetService<DbContext>();
```

Comment: Even if this appears to be a dirty hack using something that doesn't seem like I should use (ICurrentDbContext) it's working great inside it's parent dirty hack. And this is JUST where you should have put the answer, not in a comment. This is fantastic.

Comment: This fixed it for me which is what I needed until Find is implemented properly in EF7

Answer (score 8):

Find [finally arrives](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/5800) into Entity Framework core.

Comment: Cool! But how can I add it to the project? Seems no updates on nuget...

Comment: Tests are failing, after successful build it's moved to stage and then it appears in nuget, I guest.

Comment: @PavelBiryukov You have to get the prelease from their MyGet feeds.

Comment: @ShaulBehr how can I install the prelease from their MyGet feeds?

Comment: I found this link but PM command does not work for my visual studio https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetcore-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 7):

I've taken some of the previously provided answers and tweaked them to fix a couple of problems:

- Implicitly captured closure
- Key shouldn't be hard coded to "Id"

  ```
  public static TEntity Find<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set, params object[] keyValues) where TEntity : class
  {
      var context = set.GetService<DbContext>();

      var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
      var key = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();

      var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>();

      var i = 0;
      foreach (var property in key.Properties)
      {
          var i1 = i;
          entries = entries.Where(e => e.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue == keyValues[i1]);
          i++;
      }

      var entry = entries.FirstOrDefault();
      if (entry != null)
      {
          // Return the local object if it exists.
          return entry.Entity;
      }

      var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
      var query = set.AsQueryable();
      i = 0;
      foreach (var property in key.Properties)
      {
          var i1 = i;
          query = query.Where((Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)
           Expression.Lambda(
               Expression.Equal(
                   Expression.Property(parameter, property.Name),
                   Expression.Constant(keyValues[i1])),
               parameter));
          i++;
      }

      // Look in the database
      return query.FirstOrDefault();
  }
  ```

Answer (score 5):

So...the above find methods worked great, but if you don't have a column named "Id" in your model, the whole thing is going to fail on the following line.  I'm not sure why the OP would have put a hardcoded value into this spot

```
  Expression.Property(parameter, "Id"),
```

Here's a revision that will fix it for those that name our Id columns appropriately. :)

```
var keyCompare = key.Properties[0].Name;

        // TODO: Build the real LINQ Expression
        // set.Where(x => x.Id == keyValues[0]);
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "x");
        var query = set.Where((Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>)
            Expression.Lambda(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(parameter, keyCompare),
                    //Expression.Property(parameter, "Id"),
                    Expression.Constant(keyValues[0])),
                parameter));

        // Look in the database
        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

This STILL very well could fail if you have more than one Key setup on the entity object and the key you're looking up by isn't the first, but it should be quite a bit btter this way.

Comment: Better implementation at https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/pull/5800/commits/b814cc7f10bc00cdd023c782aeca1b06529ed058

Answer (score 5):

Not enough reputation to comment, but there is a bug in @Roger-Santana answer when using it in a console app/seperate assembly:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var property in key.Properties)
{
    entries = entries.Where(e => e.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue == keyValues[i]);
    i++;
}
var entry = entries.FirstOrDefault();
```

The value of 'i' is captured in the foreach so that when entries.FirstOrDefault() is called, keyValues[i] has the value of (at least) keyValues[i++], which in my case crashed with an out of index error.
A fix would be to copy the value of 'i' through the loop:

```
var i = 0;
foreach (var property in key.Properties)
{
   var idx =i;
    entries = entries.Where(e =>  e.Property(property.Name).CurrentValue == keyValues[idx]);
    i++;
}
var entry = entries.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. When I hit this bug I wasn't looking forward to figuring it out. Instantly resolved and I didn't have to use my brain. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I use `linq`; instead of `Find` method you can use:

```
var record = dbSet.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id)
```

Comment: This is different than `Find`, `Find` can return entities that have not yet been submitted to the database, i.e. before you call `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me contribute a revision that includes building the expression. 
I'll confess I didn't actually test this ;-)

```
    public static TEntity Find<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> dbSet, params object[] keyValues) where TEntity : class
    {
        // Find DbContext, entity type, and primary key.
        var context = ((IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>)dbSet).GetService<DbContext>();
        var entityType = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(TEntity));
        var key = entityType.FindPrimaryKey();

        // Build the lambda expression for the query: (TEntity entity) => AND( entity.keyProperty[i] == keyValues[i])
        var entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "entity");
        Expression whereClause = Expression.Constant(true, typeof(bool));
        uint i = 0;

        foreach (var keyProperty in key.Properties) {
            var keyMatch = Expression.Equal(
                Expression.Property(entityParameter, keyProperty.Name),
                Expression.Constant(keyValues[i++])
            );

            whereClause = Expression.And(whereClause, keyMatch);
        }

        var lambdaExpression = (Expression<Func<TEntity,bool>>)Expression.Lambda(whereClause, entityParameter);

        // Execute against the in-memory entities, which we get from ChangeTracker (but not filtering the state of the entities).
        var entries = context.ChangeTracker.Entries<TEntity>().Select((EntityEntry e) => (TEntity)e.Entity);
        TEntity entity = entries.AsQueryable().Where(lambdaExpression).First(); // First is what triggers the query execution.

        // If found in memory then we're done.
        if (entity != null) { return entity; }

        // Otherwise execute the query against the database.
        return dbSet.Where(lambdaExpression).First();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is what I use.
Not a find method, but works like a charm

```
var professionalf = from m in _context.Professionals select m;
professionalf = professionalf.Where(s => s.ProfessionalId == id);
Professional professional = professionalf.First();
```

Comment: I'm sure the OP knows about `First`. `Find` is quite different in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

An edit was proposed to change ".First()" to ".FirstOrDefault()" in the very last line of my earlier post. The edit was voted down, but I agree with it. I would expect the function to return null if the key was not found. I would not want it to throw an exception. In most cases I would want to know if the key existed in the set, and handling an exception is a very slow way of figuring that out.