# .NET - Is there a DbSet Find method in Microsoft.Data.Entity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating an MVC app with ASP.NET MVC 5, and it uses Entity Framework to work with a database.

It's a simple app with CRUD functionality to add items to a list with a database. I can create items and they save to the database, and now I want to look at a page for a specific item.

I've done this in previous applications using the `Find` method on a `DbSet` object, but that method is part of `System.Data.Entity`. I was able to create an app this way, but with ASP.NET 5, it looks like I need to configure the database connection differently, using these lines in `Startup.cs`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

This requires that I use `Microsoft.Data.Entity` instead of `System.Data.Entity`.

Here is the `MyDbContext` class:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{

    public virtual DbSet<TestModel> TestModels { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=EmptyMVCAuthentication01;integrated security=True;");
    }
}
```

I want the action to view a specific page to do something like this:

```
    public IActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Course course= db.Courses.Find(id);
        return View(course);
    }
```

(`db` above is a private instance of `MyDbContext`)

However, there's no `Find` method in `Microsoft.Data.Entity`. Any suggestions on where I can go from here?

Comment: Here is some more on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030472/dbset-doesnt-have-a-find-method-in-ef7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Find()` method does not exist in the new version of Entity framework (EF 7 as of today). As per the github [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/797) page, they added this to their backlog as so many people are requesting for `Find` and `FindAsync` methods. So this might be available in a future version.

For now, You may use `FirstOrDefault()` as needed,

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var course= db.Courses.FirstOrDefault(d=>d.Id==id);
    if(course==null)
    {
      return View("NotFound");
    }
    return View(course);
}
```

Assuming `Id` is the primary key of your `Course` model.

There are some workarounds like writing your extension methods as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030472/dbset-doesnt-have-a-find-method-in-ef7/29082410#29082410). But i prefer `FirstOrDefault()` or `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`  as they gives me what i want.