# How can i add DbContext to entity with composite primary key with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, composite-primary-key

I am newbie in Entity Framework 7 and I want to get access to edit many-to-many relation table. In Fluent API I have some code like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AB>().HasKey(x => new { x.AId, x.BId });
...
public DbSet<AB> ABs { get; set; }
```

The primary key is of the anonymous type. But I want to be able to search for my `AB` entities by primary key. Can I change anonymous PK type to specific type?

Answer (score 0):

> Can i change anonymous PK type to specific type?

No, you can't. What `HasKey` method does is configure the order of your PKs, just that, in your entity the PK properties will remain as simple properties, not as an anonymous type. So you can search an specific entity using `Find` method as I show below:

```
int aid=1;
int bid=2;
// pass the key values in the same order you define in the HasKey method
var entity= dbcontext.ABs.Find(aid,bid);
//Or
var entity= dbcontext.ABs.FirstOrDefault(ab=>ab.AId==aid && ab.BId==bid);
```

### Update

Well, now I was reading that `Find` method is not still supported, but you can find an implementation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030472/dbset-doesnt-have-a-find-method-in-ef7/29082410#29082410)