# Can't cast Int to Decimal with EF Core?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to solve an issue I have with pulling large ints (22+ digits) into ASP.Net with Entity Framework Core from a MySQL database.

EF Core does not support `BigInteger` and the suggestions I received where to use `decimal` instead. However, when using `decimal` types on my entities, I always receive the following exception when trying to select from the DB:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Int32' to type 'System.Decimal'

In the Database the columns are `INT(25)` and in my models the type is `decimal`, here is an example model:

```
[Table("alliance_reputation_rankings")]
public class AllianceReputationRank
{
    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [Column("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [Column("world")]
    public int World { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [Column("alliance")]
    public string Alliance { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [Column("rank")]
    public int Rank { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [Column("reputation")]
    public decimal Reputation { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    [Key]
    [Column("entry_id")]
    public int EntryId { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot select the `Reputation` property using EF Core. Even if I try and use `(decimal)` before the property to cast it:

**Rough example of a select:**

```
_context.AllianceReputationRankings
   .Where(p => p.Date == rank.Date && p.Alliance== rank.Alliance && p.World == rank.World)
                                   .Select(pl =>  new AllianceReputationRank
                                   {
                                       Date = pl.Date,
                                       World = pl.World,
                                       Alliance = pl.Alliance,
                                       Reputation = (decimal)pl.Reputation
                                   }
                                   ).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I use decimals in my models to bring in large ints from the database? If I cannot use decimals, how can I use large numbers with EF Core?

Comment: I think the only option is to have an unmapped property that converts the decimal value to/from BigInteger, and of course guard against overflow errors. You could give the decimal property a private setter.

Comment: @GertArnold I can't even get it as a decimal in the first place. Do you mean the Int value?

Comment: Ah no, I was thinking of using decimal in the database as well, but of course that's not what you want. I'm afraid EF is not the right tool here.

Comment: Have you tried `double` instead of `decimal`?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Also, is it possible to modify `Reputation` to be a `string`? Then you could use some workarounds and create a `BigInteger` property that parses the `string` and such (or the other way around, whichever you prefer).

Comment: @EBrown I cannot use a double, which only has 16 digits of precision, while I am using 22 digit numbers. I do math in the DB related to the numbers themselves, I would prefer to not have to represent numbers as strings if at all possible.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Do you need to update the `Reputation` column in the Database, or just read it? Additionally: do you need to update *any* of this data in the database from EF Core, or just read it?

Comment: @EBrown Read and Write

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework expects a *very* tight type-constraint between the database and model, it really doesn't like to see a numeric column with a `decimal` property. I've outlined several options here, each with it's own benefits and drawbacks. Feel free to use whichever one is the best for you.

---

Since you're using MySQL, the first option I'm outlining is that you could alter the column type from `INT(25)` to [`DECIMAL(25, 0)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html). Then you *should* be able to use [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in Entity Framework for that *as much as you want*.

If you can't do that, then, sadly, you're in a very tight corner. Entity Framework Core just *isn't* the right tool for this job, it's not mature enough. In comments you clarified that you are using this numeric column for math in the DB, which means `string` and `VARCHAR(25)` are out of the playing book, *unless* you can take that math *out* of the DB.

---

This solution relies on the assumption that this *entire* model is read-only. If it is (and you **don't** need to update the database from Entity Framework Core) then you can build a `VIEW` in MySQL that casts the `INT(25)` column to a `VARCHAR(25)`, and do something like the following:

```
[NotMapped]
public BigInteger ReputationValue { get; set; }

public string Reputation
{
    get
    {
        return ReputationValue.ToString();
    }
    set
    {
        ReputationValue = BigInteger.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

The problem is that you can't really update the database through a `VIEW`, so if you wanted to update these records (anything to do with this entire model, basically) you would need to write manual SQL, or build a stored procedure. This is just a limitation of Entity Framework Core that *can't* really be gotten around easily.

---

Lastly, the final option is to use a stored procedure / method for reading and writing. You could then pass a `WHERE` clause to it (if you want to take the challenge of building a C#-style conversion, go for it, otherwise just add a `WHERE sqlConditionCode ...` string that you pass to the method to filter things by.

Then build a second stored procedure / method to do the updates. You could call `dbContext.Update(model)` which would pass everything to the stored procedure to do the update, and `dbContext.Get("WHERE EntryId = @EntryId", new List<SqlParamter> { new SqlParamter("@EntryId", ...) })` I'm sure you get the idea by this point.

Something like:

```
public IEnumerable<AllianceReputationRank> GetAllianceReputationRanks(string whereClause, IEnumerable<MySqlParameter> parameters)
{
    // Get a connection string from somewhere
    var connectionString = string.Empty;

    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM alliance_reputation_rankings " + (whereClause ?? string.Empty), connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        foreach (var parameter in parameters)
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
        }

        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                // Build a list or use `yield return`, if building a list instance here
                var result = new List<AllianceReputationRank>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // Build a model of `AllianceReputationRank` here
                    var model = new AllianceReputationRank();

                    // Use reflection or just add each property manually
                    model.Date = reader.GetDate("date");
                    // ...

                    // Make sure you read `reputation` as a string, then `BigInteger.Parse` it to your model
                    model.Reputation = BigInteger.Parse(reader.GetString("reputation"));

                    // Either add the model to the list or `yield return model`
                    result.Add(model);
                }

                // If you built a list then `return` it
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Building the opposite method is, well, just the opposite. The `?? string.Empty` might be superfluous, I don't have an IDE in front of me to check if `string + null` will throw an exception, but you can remove it if you don't like it. (Better safe than sorry here, in my opinion.) I really hope all my types and usage is correct, if not, I apologize for any modifications needed other than adding the connection string and additional properties.

---

Honestly, the `DECIMAL(25, 0)` option should work for you, if that doesn't then the stored procedure / method option should. Both should keep your math *in* the DB and hopefully not break anything else while also fixing the Entity Framework Core issues at the same time. Is it *less than ideal*? Absolutely, and I wish it weren't what was necessary. But, unfortunately, Entity Framework Core is *very* new and still requires a lot of updates just to add simple functionality that Entity Framework not-Core has. ([Like the lack of a `.Find` method in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030472/dbset-doesnt-have-a-find-method-in-ef7), for example.)

I wish we had better news, but without the ability to build our own mappable-types (I.e. build our own `BigInteger` that is supported by Entity Framework Core) there just *isn't* a lot to be done with this problem, we're stuck to nasty work-arounds to make it do what we need to.

Answer (score 1):

What I did that seemed to work is to multiply by `1m`:

```
context.AllianceReputationRankings
   .Where(p => p.Date == rank.Date && p.Alliance== rank.Alliance && p.World == rank.World)
        .Select(pl =>  new AllianceReputationRank
        {
            Date = pl.Date,
            World = pl.World,
            Alliance = pl.Alliance,
            Reputation = pl.Reputation * 1m
        }
    ).FirstOrDefault();
```

This seems to allow decimal operations while not taking performance to the floor.